# Center a control in another control

Tags: .net, vb.net, label, panel, centering

how can I center a label inside a panel after setting the text value?

Lets say my panel is 134 pixels wide and my label is 20 letters long.

Thank you =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just center the text, not the label.

Set the label to be not AutoSized, set the width of it to be the same width as the panel, then center the text:

```
    With Label1
        .AutoSize = False
        .Width = Panel1.width
        .TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
    End With
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to change the `AutoSize`:

```
Label1.Location = New Point(Panel1.Left + CInt((Panel1.Width - Label1.Width) / 2), _
                            Label1.Top)
```

And to center it vertically too:

```
Label1.Location = New Point(Panel1.Left + CInt((Panel1.Width - Label1.Width) / 2), _
                            Panel1.Top + CInt((Panel1.Height - Label1.Height) / 2))
```